# TableView with UILocalNotification and DetailViewController

Tags: iphone, notifications, tableview, uilocalnotification

can you help me with this code?
I`m doing a app which you can add UIlocalNotifications, and those notifications goes to a tableView.

But i dont know how to do the follow one:
When i click in some row, i want the class DetailViewController take the "notification.alertbody".text , and put as Label at DetailViewController.
Someone can help me in this mettod?

this are not working!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UILocalNotification *notification = [self.notificationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[dvController.nomeMedicamento setText:[notification alertBody]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
}
```

where 'nomeMedicamento' is a @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *nomeMedicamento;  from DetailViewController

the class i have added the notification has this method:

```
- (void)addNotification {

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = self.datePicker.date;
localNotification.alertBody = self.messageField.text;
.
.
.
}
```

i want this messageField.text!

thanks and i`m sorry for my english!!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you write "this are not working!"?

Your method is not called? Your variable is not passed? Your viewController is not pushed?

Have you checked the content of `alertBody`?

```
[dvController.nomeMedicamento setText:[notification alertBody]];
NSLog(@"nomeMedicamento = %@", dvController.nomeMedicamento.text);
```